# Firebase security rules for an anonymous submission form (AngularFire)

Tags: angularjs, security, angularfire, firebase-security

After reading through Firebase's security docs, I'm confused about how to correctly configure Firebase security for a newsletter signup box on my site.  I want the public to be able to anonymously submit their signup data, but not see the submission of others.

I thought this would be as simple as revoking read privileges:

```
"rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": true
}
```

But with AngularFire, it appears that `read` privilege is required to know if there was success/error upon user submission, because I'm getting errors.

Thus, I guess my question is:  How can I configure security to allow anonymous users to see only their data submission, but no one else's?

Comment: Without seeing a sample snippet of your JSON data structure (no screenshot please) and the read/write operation that fails, this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Discovered my answer in a different section of the Firebase docs: [Anonymous Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/anonymous.html).

I didn't realize that anonymous users can authenticate through a one-time-use authentication method.  Thus, security rules would follow the example they posted:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in anonymously
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'anonymous'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```